# passing vales across different HTML FILES

Tags: javascript, html

i have three HTML files with java script as well. Now i am interested to create a forth html file to display the result of three different variables declred and used in three different html files.
i tired to used form action to import files but was not able to solve the problem.
Can one one plese suggest the best option to tackle this situation.

Comment: There is no "best option" and you can solve this _situation_ by tring yourself first, and if you have issues with your code then you can post a [mcve] and get a solution for that specific problem. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share data between your pages in many ways, generally either trough your back-end or cookies/localStorage on your front-end. To save a variable you can use `localStorage.setItem(key, value)` and you can get that variable in another page with `var my var = localStorage.getItem(key)`